# How to add my html code so as to design the page generated by a view using drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view with a page and a block. Also i have created a new content type by creating a new node--news_page.tpl.php file and a page--news.tpl.php file so as to display my block there. What am i trying to do is to edit the way news are displayed. To accomplish that i need to add my html code to the page the view created. How do i do that using drupal 7 and views3 module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view on the right-hand side there is an 'advanced' link.

When you click this it will display a number of advanced options.

The option you want is 'Theme : information".

Click on information and you will presented with a number of template suggestions to help you theme your view.

To determine what template to use you basically need to think what level you want to theme at.

**Example:**
If you click the link 'Display output' and copy/paste the code into one of the suggested file names i.e. views-view--[YOUR_VIEW].tpl.php, this is the top level you can theme at.

If you wanted to theme a particular field you will find that further down in the suggestions.

Comment: Ok i get it. So i have to locate the views-view--[MY-VIEW].tpl.php file and add my html code there? Do i need to leave some of the code there? Or i can remove anything from there? Thanks

Comment: You just need to leave the logic and be careful if removing some of the markup in case the view requires a class on that markup.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Btw i cannot find the views-view--[MY-VIEW].tpl.php file in my directory and i cannot edit the file trough drupal user interface. Do i need to change access rights or is it stored somewhere in my directory?

Comment: You just need to create a new file in the templates folder of your theme. This 'views-view--[MY-VIEW].tpl.php' is just made up, an example. If you view was called 'bananas' then your template name for a 'Display Output' would most likely be 'views-view--bananas.tpl.php You just need to pick one from the suggestions given to you.

Comment: hmm...and inside my div element i will put <?php print $output; ?> like the example drupal is giving. But will this be recognized depending the element. For example i wish the Post date to be inside a span class and the body inside to a paragraph. How will this be possible?

Comment: You need to do templates at the field level for this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4587/discussion-between-nicole-and-alex-gill)

Comment: Can you post an example? For instance to put the post date which has been created as a field in the view to be displayed inside a span class like this: <span class="gray"> <?php print $post-date ?> </span> ??? Will this be possible?

Comment: Cant chat Nicole, sorry, busy at work.

Comment: When you are viewing template suggestions, are you getting a suggestion for the post date field?

Comment: i get this $output. But also this is displayed and at the body template suggestion. Do i have to create different template for the post date field and different for the content field? I am sorry for keeping you busy! I am lost! I have tried searching in drupal and google but nothing helpful came up!

Comment: ok i see! i will have to create each template file separately. So as to be presented at the top level which is the display output. But just a question which i didnt get. After creating the display theme file called views-view--news.tpl.php i added one div element a span class for the post date. but in the block the posts will be separated with a border which is already added with the div element.  So in my two separate paragraphs i print $rows which is incorrect because i can see twice the posts. One above the border and one below.

Comment: Im not sure I understand but the file you have created is the outer most level. If you are creating files for individual fields the file will be something more like 'views-view-field--[FIELD_NAME].tpl.php'

Comment: You could if you wanted to just set the span tag and class you want within the view itself. If you click on the field you have created, there are some options. Click on 'Style settings', here you can decide what sort of tag you want and to give a class of your own.

Comment: <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?> yes i have created a file for each field. And now i am trying to retrieve each row in a div element. So if my post date id is created how do i for loop and print it at the div element correclty? i have tried <?php foreach ($rows as $created => $row): ?> <?php print $row; ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?> with no success

Comment: From what your saying you have opted for the 'Style output' template so your template file should be something like 'views-view-[SOMETHING]--default.tpl.php'. This template is for all fields.

Comment: so you are saying i have to rename my "Display output" file to views-view-[SOMETHING]--default.tpl.php ??

Comment: No. I suggest you forget about the templates and do this within the views configuation. If you click on the field you have created (left-hand side), there are some options. Click on 'Style settings', here you can decide what sort of tag you want and to give a class of your own to that field. This is far easier than tampering with templates.